# I need to populate some array of indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to populate specific index of row in mongodb.

Here is my collection

```
{

     "startTime": "00:00",
     "endTime": "23:30",
     "services": [
                ObjectId("5b90e29729d36e0014d2f6f2"),
                ObjectId("5b8f96003b918f0014bb4b92"),
                ObjectId("5b8f6273621c0f02a9ae30b9"),
                ObjectId("5b90e33329d36e0014d2f6ff"),
                ObjectId("5b8e6fd47365a5001413062e"),
                ObjectId("5b8fb97b06d94a00143a11e7"),
                ObjectId("5ba88de21aabd703443a411e"),
                ObjectId("5b98e50ed6c3f80014d3c2cf"),
                ObjectId("5b8e853f7365a500141308c1"),
                ObjectId("5b9b7832d9f1070014352893"),
                ObjectId("5bb1d6bf35c2de001301c99c")
            ],
         "isActive": true,
        "isDeleted": false,
}
```

I just need to populate these service ids ObjectId("5b90e29729d36e0014d2f6f2"),
                ObjectId("5b8f96003b918f0014bb4b92").

Comment: From where you are getting these ids `ObjectId("5b90e29729d36e0014d2f6f2"), ObjectId("5b8f96003b918f0014bb4b92")`?

Comment: I just need to populate these ids instead of all services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation in mongodb **3.6**

```
var ids = [ObjectId("5b90e29729d36e0014d2f6f2"), ObjectId("5b8f96003b918f0014bb4b92")]

db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "services",
    "pipeline": [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$_id", ids ]}}}],
    "as": "services"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Still it populates all services

Comment: why you add services as array of objects?

Comment: Post your original collection in services array and check the reponse. here https://mongoplayground.net/p/_naL5KdppxX